# Docker error when containerizing app in Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, huggingface-transformers, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to run [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) from [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/index.html) in Google Cloud Run.

My first idea was to run one of the dockerfiles provided by huggingface, but it seems that is not possible.

Any ideas on how to get around this error?

```
Step 6/9 : WORKDIR /workspace
 ---> Running in xxx
Removing intermediate container xxx
 ---> xxx
Step 7/9 : COPY . transformers/
 ---> xxx
Step 8/9 : RUN cd transformers/ &&     python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir .
 ---> Running in xxx
←[91mERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
The command '/bin/sh -c cd transformers/ &&     python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir .' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
←[0m
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build xxx completed with status "FAILURE"
```

Dockerfile from [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/docker/transformers-tensorflow-gpu):

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04
LABEL maintainer="Hugging Face"
LABEL repository="transformers"

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y bash \
                   build-essential \
                   git \
                   curl \
                   ca-certificates \
                   python3 \
                   python3-pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir \
    mkl \
    tensorflow

WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . transformers/
RUN cd transformers/ && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir .

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

.dockerignore file from Google Cloud Run [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy):

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
```

---- Edit:

Managed to get working based on the answer from Dustin. I basically:

- left the Dockerfile in the root folder, together with the transformers folder.
- updated the COPY line from the dockerfile to:

```
COPY . ./
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

This is due to these two lines in your `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY . transformers/
RUN cd transformers/ && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir .
```

This attempts to copy the local directory containing the `Dockerfile` into the container, and then install it as a Python project.

It looks like the `Dockerfile` expects to be run at the repository root of https://github.com/huggingface/transformers. You should cloning the repo and move the `Dockerfile` you want to build into the root, and then build again.

Comment: Thanks Dustin, problem was indeed on that COPY line. I will update the question with what I did to make it work.